# error: bad class file...com/smartfofserver/openspace/OpenSpaceExtension.class .... class file has wrong version 50.0, it should be 49.0

Tags: java, smartfoxserver

I am getting an error : **"bad OpenSpaceExtention.class file which is imported from com.smartfofserver/openspace.OpenSpaceExtension**;   and  ..... **class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0"**  While running **ant**  which for to generate corresponding package class file and jar files simultaneously from my project.

I am using **OpenSpaceExtention.jar** file in my project and it has version 1.6: 50.*.

Thank you for your support .

Regards...
sreenivas.
seenumd@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with `source` and `target` version specified in your ant `javac` task.  If you post relevant ant snippet, perhaps someone can give a better solution.

Comment: @seenu, please edit your question with the ant snippet and not post it as comment

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when your JVM is of higher version compared to your compiler. Say you have a JRE of 1.6 and you try to run a class which was an output of compiler 1.5 then this issue occurs.your question is not clear. make sure you have the class files compiled and run by same versions of java. To check more use javac -version which gives the version of compiler and java -version to check the version of JRE

Comment: <project>   <target name="game">
 <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src/sierra"
  destdir="${basedir}/build"
  debug="on"
  deprecation="false">
     <classpath>
                <path refid="build.classpath"/>
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/libs/json.jar"/>
 
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/libs/jysfs.jar"/>
  <pathelement location="${basedir}/libs/OpenSpaceExtension.jar"/>
            </classpath> <include name="sfsPizzaGameIntegration/*.java"/>
 </javac>
 <jar jarfile="${basedir}/build/sfsPizzaGameIntegration.jar"
  basedir="${basedir}/build">
 </jar> 
</target>
</project>

Comment: Ant is just a script to compile,package the class files.Just type these commands and see the output                                javac -version   java -version

Answer (score 0):

Please share some more details about your JDK and JRE versions.

For your reference below are the java version details

- Java 1.2 uses major version 46.
- Java 1.3 uses major version 47.
- Java 1.4 uses major version 48.
- Java 5 uses major version 49.
- Java 6 uses major version 50.
- Java 7 uses major version 51.
- Java 8 uses major version 52.
- Java 9 uses major version 53.

If you are working with Java 5, try to upgrade to Java 6